# Can C++ infer type of non-type template argument and enforce the type on the rest of template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, auto, non-type-template-parameter

Consider this struct. It is a range, but uses template instead of constructor, making the values static:

```
template <int min_v, int max_v>
struct num_range final {
  constexpr static int min = min_v;
  constexpr static int max = max_v;
}
// now you can do
std::cout << num_range<1,3>::min << '\n'; // prints 1
```

But this is fixed to `int`. What if I wanted C++ to deduce the numeric type from the first argument and enforce it on the second argument?

I tried this:

```
template <typename TNumber>
template <TNumber min_v, TNumber max_v>
struct num_range final
```

I tried that at the reverse order. I know you can do this:

```
template <auto min_v, decltype(min_v) max_v>
struct num_range final {
    using num_type = decltype(min_v);
    constexpr static num_type min = min_v;
    constexpr static num_type max = max_v;
};
```

But I don't think `auto` template argument is allowed in C++17, which is what I am targeting. It also does not seem to enforce the type on the second template argument, as this compiles just fine:

```
std::cout << num_range<-10, 12U>::min << '\n'; // prints -10
```

Bonus points if you know how to do this with variadric template, enforcing all numbers to be same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't think auto template argument is allowed in C++17

It is allowed in C++17.

> It also does not seem to enforce the type on the second template argument

Yes, some implicit conversions are permitted when passing template arguments. Do this instead:

```
template <auto min_v, auto max_v>
struct num_range
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(min_v), decltype(max_v)>);
    constexpr static auto min = min_v;
    constexpr static auto max = max_v;
};
```

Or in C++20:

```
template <auto min_v, auto max_v>
requires std::is_same_v<std::is_same_v<decltype(min_v), decltype(max_v)>
struct num_range
{
    constexpr static auto min = min_v;
    constexpr static auto max = max_v;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original approach does work, you just haven't made it noticeable:

```cpp
using range = num_range<static_cast<signed char>(0), 200>;
```

clang rejects this:

```
<source>:8:54: error: non-type template argument evaluates to 200, which cannot be narrowed to type 'decltype('\x00')' (aka 'signed char') [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    8 | using range = num_range<static_cast<signed char>(0), 200>;
      |
```

In your example `num_range<-10, 12U>`, `12U` can be converted to `int` (the type of `-10`), so everything compiles fine.

Admittedly, this behavior is surprising, since `-10` and `12U` are still different types and it's intuitively wrong that `num_range<-10, 12U>` compiles, but implicit conversions make it work. If you want to prevent this, you will have deduce both types separately and then check whether they are the same (@HolyBlackCat has offered two solutions for this).

> But I don't think auto template argument is allowed in C++17

It is, see [cppreference: Template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

> Bonus points if you know how to do this with variadric template, enforcing all numbers to be same type.

```cpp
template <auto Head, decltype(Head)... Tail>
/* ... */
```

Or, similar to @HolyBlackCat's solution, using `std::enable_if`:

```cpp
template <auto Head, auto... Tail, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<decltype(Head), decltype(Tail)> && ...), int> = 0>
/* ... */
```

Comment: Oh, thanks... So this would presumably work for an arbitrary set of numbers too?

Comment: @TomášZato (Assuming you're talking about your original solution.) While it would work for >2 numbers, it's probably not a good idea (even for 2 numbers) due to not being symmetric. If you want `num_range<-10, 12U>` to compile, there should probably be a more elaborate logic of choosing the type, instead of just taking the first type (something that doesn't depend on the order).

Comment: Also rejected by gcc: `error: narrowing conversion of '200' from 'int' to 'char' [-Wnarrowing]`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I kinda figured that if you want all of them to be of same type, you can compare all of them to any one of them and the first one seemed easiest.